# How to handle "Default constructor cannot handle exception type ClassNotFoundException" error

Tags: java, jdbc

The error is "Default constructor cannot handle exception type ClassNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"
in the " = new DriveStore()" declaration in this class

```
import ..... ;

@WebServlet("/create_drive")
public class create_Drice extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DriveStore drive_store = new DriveStore();
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ...
        ...
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

try-catch block outside doGet() and doPost did not work and drive_store is used in both.
How could this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the compile error is that the creation of a `DriveStore` instance using the default constructor might throw a `ClassNotFoundException`, but the Compiler can neither automatically handle the exception nor rethrow it, because the implicit default constructor of the shown class `create_Drice` does not declare any exceptions (implicit constructors can never throw declared exceptions in Java).

As the error message says, the fix is to add an explicit constructor to the `create_Drice` class. This constructor can either declare and throw the exception like this:

```
public class create_Drice {
    
    private DriveStore drive_store;
    
    public create_Drice() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        drive_store = new DriveStore();
    }

}
```

... or it can handle the exception in some way:

```
public class create_Drice {
    
    private DriveStore drive_store;
    
    public create_Drice() {
        try {
            drive_store = new DriveStore();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create DriveStore", exc);
        }
    }

}
```

The "handling" of the exception shown here is the conversion to a runtime exception, which does not have to be declared in Java. Of course you can implement some other way to handle the exception.